# Masonite - TypeError > encoding without a string argument when using the Auth login method

Tags: python, frameworks, masonite

When logging in i keep getting a `TypeError > encoding without a string argument` exception. I am doing it with the out of the box `LoginController` that ships with Masonite.

The login route is fine but it keeps throwing this exception when logging in.

Here is the code snippet:

```py
def store(self, request: Request, auth: Auth):
    if auth.login(request.input('email'), request.input('password')):
        return request.redirect('/home')

    return request.redirect('/login')
```

Answer (score 0):

This is most likely because one of your inputs are missing. If one of the inputs is missing it will be of value `None` which will cause this exception.

Check the value of password and make sure it is not of type `None`.

Comment: Yes this was the issue. I refactored my form and I forgot to put the `name` attribute on that input field